# WCM Authoring infrastructure

Tags: web

I'm working in a SharePoint migration. My client has 2 front end machines for production environment and 2 front end machines for quality environment. The content is authored in quality and migrated to production. In the production machines, there's no authoring capabilities for security reasons.

How can i reproduce this in SharePoint?

How can i remove all html references for ribbon, css and JS that are SP specific in production machines?

I only want that in Quality. Production has to hide the fact that is working in a SharePoint environment (ViewSource).

I don't want anyone to realize the Content Management is done in SharePoint.

Answer (score -1):

the SharePoint Publishing infrastructure is what controls the publishing pattern you are describing. Content Deployment is a feature which handles publishing content from one site to another site (even another site on another farm). Read up on 
these features to get a better understanding.

Branding and Masterpage customizations are the answer to your second question. You can insert custom code to hide the ribbon controls, and apply  customized CSS and Masterpages to hide/expose functionality. This is a developer skill, not and administrator skill.

Both sites will have the same branding/css and  Masterpage in order for Content Deployment to work, which is why you need programming logic to make them appear different on the two sites.